# Django's I18N with third-party apps

Tags: django, internationalization, django-tagging

I have a Django project which uses `django-tagging` and is supposed to run in German. So I looked into the sources and found that `django-tagging` does indeed use `gettext_lazy` and is thus completely translatable. However, there are no translations available in the package. So I assume there must be a way for me to translate it from within my project.

In other words, I expect `./manage.py makemessages -a` to include untranslated strings from `django-tagging`, but apparently I'm wrong to expect that.

So, how do I manage this situation properly? Will translating `django-tagging` in the upstream repository work as expected?

Answer (score 5):

You can create gettext messages in django-tagging directory and contribute translations to project leader:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l de
```

If you want to create message catalog in your project directory, you should install or symlink app (check -S option of makemessages) in your project directory. Then use manage.py makemessages command as above.

If you want to see more details about translating 3rd part apps, please check:

http://source.mihelac.org/2010/07/31/handling-i18n-in-django-projects/

Answer (score 2):

Within my project directory I make a symlink to that third party app and run my makemessages command with the '--symlinks' option:

../manage.py makemessages -l nl --symlinks

then I remove my symlink

Answer (score 0):

Detailed:

```
ln -s full/path/to/installed/app/folder path/to/folder/with/symlinks/in/your/project
```

and then run

`django-admin.py makemessages --locale=*lang* --symlinks`

for instance if i want translate `django-tagging`:

```
 ln -s /home/user/python_projects/agregator_gitlab/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tagging /home/user/python_projects/agregator_gitlab/agregator/site_aggregator_backend/extra-locales/tagging
```

(my manage.py locates `agregator/site_aggregator_backend/manage.py`)

and

`django-admin.py makemessages --locale=uk --symlinks`

and all work perfectly!