# Django il8n - Translating external apps on windows

Tags: python, django, windows, localization, translation

I am new to Django translations. I used to translate everything by hard coding my translated strings into the right spots, but I am developing a serious application now, and want to do it right.

I need to translate an external application (the excellent django-allauth), so I figured I could copy over its german translation into my own translation file, translate everything, and go with it. Later I plan to contribute my Portuguese translation back to the allauth project.

However, Django marks my translation strings as comments when I do `manage.py makemessages`, because it can't find any use for them. Here are the first few lines of the file:

```
#~ msgid "Password"
#~ msgstr "Passwort"

#~ msgid "Password must be a minimum of {0} characters."
#~ msgstr "Das Passwort muss aus mindestens {0} Zeichen bestehen."

#~ msgid "Remember Me"
#~ msgstr "Angemeldet bleiben"

#~ msgid "E-mail address"
#~ msgstr "E-Mail-Adresse"
```

I have found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933824/djangos-i18n-with-third-party-apps) and read the nice guide at http://source.mihelac.org/2010/07/31/handling-i18n-in-django-projects/, which asks that we use Symlinks to help makemessages find the translation strings. But I am on Windows. No symlinks for me.

How can I translate this external app without adding it to my project folder? I am using git, Windows Server 2003, and Django 1.4

Comment: NTFS supports symlinks, but offers no tools to manage them. To symlink folders I use [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) of SysInternal fame. For files, I use this [build of coreutils to get ln on windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but in the end I translated the external project myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up forking the project and translating it myself. Then I set the corresponding requirements.txt entry to point to my fork.

I could've used @ixe013's nice suggestion, but I figured this way would be more direct, since I wanted to contribute the translations to the project anyway.